# How to find out if str has any number

Tags: python, string, digit

I have a question. If I have a string, for example:

```
str1 = 'Wazzup1'
```

and numbers:

```
nums = '1234567890'
```

I need a code that will look into str1 and tell me if it has any number(not all of them). Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `any` function, which returns a Boolean which is true iff at least one of the elements in the iterable is true.

```
string = 'Wazzup1'
result = any(c.isdigit() for c in string)
print(result) # True
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#any) and a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

```
any(x in nums for x in str1)
```

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> str1 = 'Wazzup1'
>>> nums = '1234567890'
>>> any(x in nums for x in str1)
True
>>>
```

---

Note that the above is for when you have a custom set of numbers to test for.  However, if you are just looking for digits, then a cleaner approach would be to use [`str.isdigit`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
>>> str1 = 'Wazzup1'
>>> any(x.isdigit() for x in str1)
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

As most Python programmers will tell you, the most concise way to do this is using:

```
any(x in nums for x in str1)
```

However, if you're new to Python or need a better grasp of the basics of string manipulation, then you should learn how to do this using more fundamental tools.

You can access the individual elements of a string, list, tuple, or any other *iterable* in Python using square brackets around an index.  The characters of a string are indexed starting from 0 (e.g. `"hello"[0]` gives `"h"`).

Using a for loop, the solution is easier to understand for a Python newbie than the above-mentioned `any` solution:

```
result = False
for i in range(len(str1)):
    if str1[i] in nums:
        result = True
```

A Python for loop can also iterate directly over the elements of the string:

```
result = False
for x in str1:
    if x in nums:
        result = True
```

In the first code snippet in this post, the expression `x in nums for x in str1` uses Python's *list comprehension* feature.  This goes through every element `x` of `str1` and finds the result of `x in nums`.  `any(x in nums for x in str1)` returns `True` if (and only if) at least one of these results is `True` (meaning a numerical digit is in `str1`).  This is much like the second `for` loop example given in this post, and many Python programmers choose this option because it is concise and still understandable by other Python programmers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and [`string.digits`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.digits) to check whether the string contain a digit:

```
import string

if any(x in string.digits for x in str1):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a regular expression:

```
>>> str1 = 'Wazzup1'
>>> import re
>>> bool(re.search(r'\d', str1))
True
```

Note: there might be a difference in how `c.isdigit()`, `c in nums`, `int(c)` and `\d` define what is a digit due to locale or Unicode.